# NodeJS Request: How to get the response as a string?

Tags: node.js, express, node-request

I'm kind of lost.  Is it possible to get the response body as a string in `.on(response)` (see below)?  Or am I crazy?  I know I can `.pipe` the response to a `WriteStream`, but I need both the response body and the response statusCode at the same place in order to continue my code. Thanks!

```
var request = require("request");
request(url)
.on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode); // 200
    console.log(/* I need to get response body string here */); // <--- can I have the response body as a string here?
})
.on("error", function(err){
    console.log("Problem reaching URL: ", err);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would make in a comment, but I can't.

As in the npm page (considering you don't need pipe), you can have the body along with the response in: :

```
var request = require("request");

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
  console.log('body:', body); 
});
```